# How to parse json data using singleton class

Tags: ios

I have a singleton class where i have implemented a method to parse json data through URL. The code is as below

```
-(id)parseJsonDataWIthURL:(NSString *)url :(NSString*)datumm
{

    NSMutableDictionary *arrrrr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];



            NSMutableURLRequest *reqqq=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

            NSData *dataaa=[datumm dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [reqqq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [reqqq setHTTPBody:dataaa];

            NSURLSessionConfiguration *configg=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession*sessionn=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configg delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

            NSURLSessionDataTask *taskk=[sessionn dataTaskWithRequest:reqqq completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *responce,NSError *error){
                if(error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }else{
                    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"data %@",d);
                    [arrrrr setDictionary:d];
                }
            }];
            [taskk resume];


    return arrrrr;
}
```

The method returns no values, it is because the blocks takes time to execute within that method returns the result. So is there any way to wait until block completes and return the value.

Comment: Use a completion block, notifications or delegate. But since it's async, `grrrrr ` will contains no value when return.

Comment: How to use completion block in my code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ragul ml,

Simplest solution I can suggest is to use blocks :)

Here is how you can achieve it :) modify `-(id)parseJsonDataWIthURL:(NSString *)url :(NSString*)datumm` to,

```
-(void)parseJsonDataWIthURL:(NSString *)url :(NSString*)datumm withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *))completionBlock 
{

    NSMutableDictionary *arrrrr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];



            NSMutableURLRequest *reqqq=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

            NSData *dataaa=[datumm dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [reqqq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [reqqq setHTTPBody:dataaa];

            NSURLSessionConfiguration *configg=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession*sessionn=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configg delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

            NSURLSessionDataTask *taskk=[sessionn dataTaskWithRequest:reqqq completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *responce,NSError *error){
                if(error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    completionBlock(nil)
                }else{
                    NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"data %@",d);
                    [arrrrr setDictionary:d];
                    if (completionBlock) {
                          completionBlock(arrrrr);
                    }
                }
            }];
            [taskk resume];
}
```

finally modify your call as,

```
[[YourSingletonClass sharedInstance] parseJsonDataWIthURL:your_url :datumm withCompletionBlock:^(NSMutableArray *array) {
        if (array){
            //web service is successful
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you very much sandeep, it worked for me. Is withCompletionBlock is a custom block??

Comment: yeah :) You have declared it in method defination :) This is the block defination (void(^)(NSMutableArray *)) which means this block takes NSMutableArray as argument does not return anything :) '^' indicates that it is a block :)